# Foundation 5 - Responsive bg IMG & Div Heights

Tags: html, css, image, height

I have two issues that I'm not sure how to fix.

1. My background image does not scale on tablets and mobile devices. Do I have to use interchange to make it responsive? I set the size to cover because it's a fixed image. I think that is causing the issue, but not sure what the correct way it.
2. Again on mobile, the bottom overlay height doesn't fill the div.

It's in div id="wrapper-two"  | 
                div id="about-overlay"

The URL to the page is: http://www.pickettcreative.com/indexTest.html

This is a test page on my live site, so the pickettMain.css does not apply to this page.

Answer (score 0):

answer to your first question is set background img to html instead of body.
This will cause the img to resize and work properly on mobiles. (idk why this is)

2 try using `height:100%;`?